# Destroy objects and their bindings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this class in JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    this.testObject = function() {
        /*options*/
        this.options = arguments[0];
    };

    /*make object*/
    testObject.prototype.make = function(){

        this.targetElement = document.getElementById('testDiv');

        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            ...
        });
        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            ...
        });
        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            ...
        });

    };
}());

var test; // I need this to be global
function callObject(){
    test = new testObject({...});
    test.make();
}
```

This object binds some events. the instantiation is also inside another function. this is because I have situations that adding new elements to DOM, so calling `callObject()` for every new element to bind events for it.

But I think there is a performance issue here, it's going slow when I call `callObject` multiple times. I do not know what is the problem in fact.

So how can I delete an object and all it's bound events?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: So long as you don't use `var` to declare the variable, you can call delete on it to remove it from the global (window) object.

Comment: Using an IIFE for this is pointless. IIFEs are used to avoid the use of global variables, but this creates properties of the global object from within the IIFE. It has the cons of an IIFE without the benefits, consider using a plain function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> var test; // I need this to be global
> function callObject(){
>     test = new testObject({...});
>     test.make();
> }
```

In the above, *test* will only reference the last instance of *testObject*.

The pattern you're using means that every function on the prototype chain has a closure to the execution context of the outer IIFE, and so does every listener added by the *make* method. That's inefficient if you don't need the closures. If not, then using an IIFE here isn't suitable, consider using a standard approach (it's convention to give constructors a name starting with a capital letter):

```
function TestObject() {
    /*options*/
    this.options = arguments[0];
}

TestObject.prototype.make = function (){
    this.targetElement = document.getElementById('testDiv');
    this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e){
        ...
    };
    this.targetElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e){
        ...
    };
    ...
};
```

As noted elsewhere, adding listeners using function expressions makes it difficult to remove them later. The above pattern also means that each instance has its own copy of the function. An alternative that solves both these issues is to use references. You might add them as properties of the constructor so that they don't create additional global variables and don't need another object, e.g.

```
TestObject.mousedown = function (e){ ... };
TestObject.mouseup   = function (e){ ... };

TestObject.prototype.make = function(){
    var TO = TestObject;
    this.targetElement = document.getElementById('testDiv');
    this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousedown', TO.mousedown, false);
    this.targetElement.addEventListener('mouseup',  TO.mouseup, false);
    ...
};
```

Which avoids a lot of closures and unnecessary copies of functions and means listeners can be removed by name. And you might want to make the *test* global an object or array so you can keep references to all instances of *TestObject*, not just the last one.

Comment: thanks but what if there is a default event script for class itself? for example a default `mouseup` event that should run for each object of this class. I want it to be DRY.

Comment: That's what the above does. There is one instance of *TestObject.mouseup*, a reference to it is attached to each *targetElement*. Incidentally, there are no classes in ECMAScript. The next version (ed 6) introduces classes and they are different to the above, so calling objects created by *new* and using prototypes a "class" will get very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider. First, and most importantly, your event listeners have anonymous functions. You CAN'T unbind a listener when you give it an anon function. So go ahead and make actual functions for those. Then you can call `removeEventListener` the same way you called `addEvent...` and it will detach those listeners.

What I normally do is make a `destroy` function that removes all listeners and sets any global vars to `null`. Then you can call that destroy function whenever you need to.

Comment: "*You CAN'T unbind a listener when you give it an anon function*", you can, sort of, by replacing the node with a clone of itself, which will remove all listeners added by *addEventListener*. Bit of a hack though…

Comment: I suppose... but considering there is a perfectly valid and long supported way to remove listeners, I don't see why you would do this. Seems to just promote bad & inefficient code.